# Percentage change calculation with dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Hi I have a dataframe like below and I would like to see a monthly pct change in unique user counts

| month | user_id | first_month | Number of sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 12334 | 2022-01-01 | 5 |
| 2022-03-01 | 11344 | 2022-02-01 | 9 |

What I did was the below.

`newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['first_month','month'])['user_id'].nunique()).reset_index()`

`newdf.groupby(['first_month','month'])['user_id'].pct_change()`

However when doing this I just got a return full of nulls. Can someone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```py
df.groupby(['first_month','month'])['user_id'].nunique().to_frame().pct_change().reset_index()
```

You can also swap `.to_frame()` and `.pct_change()` with each other. Output:

```py
  first_month      month  user_id
0  2022-01-01 2022-04-01      NaN
1  2022-02-01 2022-03-01      0.0
```

---

**However,**

This is how you can also do it:

```py
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(['first_month','month'])['user_id'].nunique().pct_change().set_axis(df.index)
```

```py
       month  user_id first_month  Number of sales  pct_change
0 2022-04-01    12334  2022-01-01                5         NaN
1 2022-03-01    11344  2022-02-01                9         0.0
```